# How to parse data from HTML tables into Julia data structures

Tags: html, parsing, dataframe, julia

I wanted to read through an HTML page, which has a table and load that table into a Dataframe in Julia. Any ideas on how I could go about it? Are there any existing packages which might be helpful?

To be specific, I wanted to get the contents of the table on this webpage: http://mlr.cs.umass.edu/ml/datasets.html

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there are HTML parsers written in Julia neither; if you have time you could write a binding for [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) or [Gumbo](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser), written in C.

Update: a Gumbo wrapper now exists: https://github.com/porterjamesj/Gumbo.jl

Comment: reading the Gumbo github page it appears to be C rather than C++

Comment: @MrAlpha I think you are talking about [this](https://github.com/porterjamesj/Gumbo.jl); it didn't exist when I wrote this answer, I'll add it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any tools to do this. It seems like the fastest solution would be to find some code in R or Python that does this and translate it.